# Pass Servlet variable to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page which I use to submit some data to a `HTTPServelet`. I need to show an alert after successfully completing task in servlet so I have a JavaScript AJAX function which executes in `onSubmit` event of JSP Page. but when I click submit button AJAX function does not execute with it.

Here is my Javascript function:

```
function alerts(servlet) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", servlet, true);
    console.log("connected to "+servlet);
    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { //this function does not execute
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {

            if (xhr.status === 200) {

                content = xhr.responseText;
                var objects = JSON.parse(content);
                console.log(objects);

                var elemant = document.getElementById("tblObjects");
                var child = elemant.children;
                var childLength = child.length;
                if (0 < child.length) {
                    for (i = 0; i < childLength; i++) {
                        deleteElamant("tblObj");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    };
}
```

And my Servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        try {
            //Do somethings inside Servlet

            response.getWriter().write("my alert messege to JavaScript");
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/NextServlet");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } 
    }
```

Comment: `var objects = JSON.parse(content);` and `response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");` don't belong together.

Comment: `//this function does not execute` - What are you doing to determine that?

Comment: try doing with jquery,code will be much smaller and easier to understand

Comment: @Quentin I have put some breakpoints in Firefox debug console and debugged it line by line. it does not went inside onreadystatechange. I have a similar function that I use to do some background search about textbox inputs. it runs without any issue.

Comment: @Quentin I am passing a `jsonArray` as a `String` in my servlet. so is it an issue that I use responce type as text/html.?

Comment: @Sajirupee What does this mean `content = xhr.responseText;` ?

Comment: @sankrish assigning response values from servlet.

Comment: @Sajirupee do u want to try using jquery?i can help u wid that..

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone I have found the solution. thanks for helping everyone.